# How to find running containers using terminal?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, windows-10, google-kubernetes-engine, docker-desktop

I see there are some containers running on my docker desktop app, but when I try `docker ps` on CMD I see nothing as result(empty table) and the result of `kubectl get pods` is the following:

```
NAME                               READY   STATUS             RESTARTS      AGE
client-depl-cdf975567-vzgw6        0/1     ImagePullBackOff   7 (34m ago)   12h
comments-depl-76c5bc6948-6fz4s     0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0 (44m ago)   12h
event-bus-depl-69cfbf58f7-slpjc    0/1     ImagePullBackOff   8             12h
moderation-depl-786f4ffc65-kfwh4   0/1     ImagePullBackOff   1 (40m ago)   12h
posts-depl-5f9b5c5774-wjv59        0/1     ImagePullBackOff   11            12h
query-depl-5d7d567fc7-vclfv        0/1     ImagePullBackOff   8             12h
```

I don't know how to stop the running containers and delete all the images? When I try it using the GUI app they create themselves again automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to delete the corresponding workload resource (`Deployment`, `Statefulset` etc) which are controlling your K8s cluster. Workloads by default come with `restartPolicy` as `Always`, due to which your Pods are getting recreated after deletion.

To list the a workload resource, run the following command:

```
# kubectl get <workload-resource name> -A
# -A flag prints the resources present in all namespaces.
kubectl get deploy -A
kubectl get daemonset -A
kubectl get stateful -A
```

Copy the name of the resource from the printed list and delete it:

```
kubectl delete <resource-type> <resource-name>
kubectl delete deploy client-depl
```

Comment: Isn't there a command to delete all of them at the same time without specifying the names?

Comment: you try the `--all` flag e.g `kubectl delete deploy --all -A`

Answer (score 1):

you can see all running containers using:

```
kubectl get deploy -A
```

for delete them :

```
kubectl delete deploy client-depl
```

Comment: Isn't there a command to delete all of them at the same time without specifying the names?

Answer (score 1):

To delete these you might need to delete deployment , daemonset & statefulsets. If you delete a pod it might just deleted that particular pod but replicas in the deployment will re-spin a new pod hence you should be deleting the deployment.

`kubectl get deployment -A` lists all the deployment running in your cluster.
`kubectl get daemonset -A` lists all the daemonset running in your cluster.
`kubectl get statefulset -A` lists all the statefulset running in your cluster.

To delete these use `kubectl delete deployment <deployment-name> -n <namespace>` Similarly replace deployment with statefulset and daemonset to delete that resource.

Once this is done to delete unused images use `docker image prune -a` this will delete all unused images from your machine. If you need to remove other docker resources like unused containers, newtworks run `docker system prune -a`

[docker system prune document](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/)

Images could be delete from Docker desktop as well for doing this refer the below screenshot : [image: Delete dangling & unused images using docker desktop]

Delete all pods in a namespace. Make sure you are connected to the right cluster before running this command :

```
kubectl delete --all pods --namespace=foo
```

Comment: Isn't there a command to delete all of them at the same time without specifying the names?

Comment: Can you try to run this command ? Be careful it will delete all the pods in the namespace make sure your connected to the right cluster. Updated ny answer

Answer (score 1):

To see all the running Kubernetes container

```
kubectl get po -o jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{"pod: "}{.metadata.name}{"\n"}{range .spec.containers[*]}{"\tname: "}{.name}{"\n\timage: "}{.image}{"\n"}{end}'
```

for delete them :

```
kubectl delete deploy deployment-obj
```

Comment: I just copied and pasted your command and got `error: error parsing jsonpath '{range, unclosed action`